# Insert an attribute to input field when user selects a radio

Tags: javascript, input, attributes, insert, field

I need a JavaScript that can insert an attribute to a field and also remove it when the user deselects the field.

Here is the code I'm using for the radio select:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='sel']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#sel" + test).show();
    });

    if (test == "CreditCard") {
        $("#card").addClass("validate[custom[card]] text-input");
    } else {
        $("#card).removeClass("validate[custom[card]] text-input");
    }
});
</script>
```

Field code:

```
<table><tr><td>

<p>
Credit/Debit Card<lable  style="margin-right:1px;"></lable><input type="radio" name="sel" id="sel"  value="CreditCard" />
</p> 
<p>
Paypal<input type="radio" id="sel"  name="sel" value="Paypal"   />
</p>
<p>
Wire Transfer<input type="radio" id="sel"  name="sel" value="WireTransfer"  />
</p>
<!====================================================================================>
</td><td>
<!====================================================================================>
<div id="selCreditCard" class="desc">

<label for="card"><strong>Card Number<font color=red size=3> *</font></strong></label>
        <input name="card"   type="text"  id="card" value=""  style="width:85px;" />  
</div>
<!====================================================================================>
<div id="selPaypal" class="desc" style="display: none;margin-left:20px;margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:1px;">
    paypal
</div>
<!====================================================================================>
<div id="selWireTransfer" class="desc" style="display: none;margin-left:20px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:-5px;">

Transfer

</div>
<!====================================================================================>
</td></tr></table>
​
```

This is the attribute that needs to be inserted to the "card" input field:

```
class="validate[custom[card]] text-input"
```

When the user selects the radio with the value `CreditCard`, the attribute will be inserted to the input field, and when the user deselects the radio with the  value `CreditCard` the attribute will be removed.

Link for fiddle:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ECUN8/3/)

Comment: You seem to be using jQuery. You could use `.addClass` and `.removeClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

telexper, there are lots of wrong things in your code, and unfortunatelly i dont have the time to explain right now.

but i will leave a working code for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/DSrLS/

just click "Credit/Debit Card" and the class `nowitsadded` wil be added to the input field, which will turn red.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="sel1" name="sel"> Credit/Debit Card

<br>

<input type="radio" id="sel2" name="sel"> Paypal

<br>

<input type="radio" id="sel3" name="sel"> Wire Transfer

<br>
<br>

<div id="selCreditCard" class="desc">
    Card Number <input name="card" type="text" id="card" value="">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#sel1').click(function() { $('#card').addClass('nowitsadded') })
```

**CSS**

```
.nowitsadded {background-color: red}
```

Comment: how do i add this class="validate[custom[card]] text-input" to the input field

Comment: i just showed you how to add a class! replace `nowitsadded` with your class name.